# Find which rows in a data frame have negative values?

Tags: r

I have a data frame called `y` and I want to know exactly which rows have at least one negative number so I can select those rows of y and inspect them myself. I tried a few different ways but they gave me strange results so I ended up writing the following for loop:

```
temp <- NULL
# Check for negative values
for(i in 1:nrow(y)) {
  for(j in 1:length(y)) {
    if(y[i,j] < 0) {
      temp[i] <- i
    }
  }
}
na.omit(temp)
```

This gave me what I wanted, but I'm pretty sure there's an easier way to code that. Maybe using apply or lapply or something else. Can anyone help me find more efficient code that gives me the row numbers of the rows that have at least one negative value? To be clear, I want the row numbers only

Answer (score 2):

You can try `which` like below

```
which(y<0,arr.ind = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dplyr with `rowwise()` and `rowSums()`:

```
creating toy dataframe:

df<-data.frame(a=c(2,6,0,8), b=c(2,7,5,0), c=c(1,0,2,8), d=c(4,3,8,5))
> df
  a b c d
1 2 2 1 4
2 6 7 0 3
3 0 5 2 8
4 8 0 8 5
```

solution with base R using `apply()` with `MARGIN=1`:

```
df$has_negatives<-apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x<0))
df
  a b c d has_negatives
1 2 2 1 4     FALSE
2 6 7 0 3      TRUE
3 0 5 2 8      TRUE
4 8 0 8 5      TRUE
```

Solution with dplyr:

```
df%>%rowwise()%>%mutate(has_negatives=rowSums(across(everything(), ~(.<0))))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Rowwise: 
      a     b     c     d has_negatives
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1     2     2     1     4         0
2     6     7     0     3         1
3     0     5     2     8         1
4     8     0     8     5         1
```

Comment: I tried a variation of my second answer with any(): `df%>%rowwise()%>%mutate(has_zeros=any(c(a,b,c,d)==0))`, which worked. Do anyone know how to do it with some sort of `anything()`, so I could call it over all columns without naming them? I could not find a way